# How to add order column in page admin wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I spent most of the day on this but couldn't find any solution.
Could you tell me how to add order column in page(admin) in WordPress?

Comment: order col. means? sorting?

Comment: Specify proper what you want

Comment: For example: when we create new page, we can set the page order.Then I want to show "order" column in the page admin listing.

Comment: you want to show as read only view? that what order set for specific page when page created?

Comment: There are plugins for this, or you can also code it yourself: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need adding the column to the pages list page
Following Code will add column to your pages listing,

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'my_columns');

function my_columns($columns) {
    $columns['order'] = 'Order';
    return $columns;
}

add_action('manage_pages_custom_column',  'my_show_columns');

function my_show_columns($name) {
    global $post;

    switch ($name) {
        case 'order':
            $views = $post->menu_order;
            echo $views;
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry, how can I put it after "Title"?

Comment: Change the my_columns function with following function my_columns($columns) {
    $crunchify_columns = array();
    $title = 'title';
    foreach($columns as $key => $value) {
        $crunchify_columns[$key] = $value;
        if ($key==$title){
            $crunchify_columns['order'] = 'Order';   
        }
    }
    return $crunchify_columns;
}

Comment: Thanks so much for paying much attention on my question.

Comment: Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

@chhorn Soro, you need to go through with this nice answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43970/adding-menu-order-column-to-custom-post-type-admin-screen.

it will help you out to display/add new field in listing

Answer (score 0):

This free plugin gives you the possibility to add an order column to all of your overview pages, along with a lot of other cool columns.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/